# Change look of Segmented Control in IOS 6 and 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

Our large IOS app has a bunch of Segmented controls.
The new IOS 7 B&W look - looks like crap in our app.
I can change the background color (and set the corner radius) so we have colored buttons again - BUT it then looks like crap when run on an IOS 6 phone.
For IOS 6 I have to change the Tint color and NOT change the background color.

Adding conditional code to do this for each individual control would be a royal pain.  Creating a subclass to do this - and modifying all the XIB's to use it - would also be a pain.

Is there any way to modify the look of a control for the entire app?  Can a class extension do this?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the apparence of the UISegmentedControl class

something like

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

set your layout in *application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*, using the standard ugly iOS version test to set the different layouts according to the current version

API's reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

You can find in UISegmentedControl's API the specific appearence fields
https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807-CH3-SW33